# TypeScript does not use generic key consistently

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-5

In the following code I use a generic that extends the key of an interface. TypeScript incorrectly allows me to use types from different properties of the object, unless I explicitly pass in a key as a generic or argument.

```
interface Versions {
  v1: {
    input: {
      v1Input: boolean
    }
    output: {
      v1Output: boolean
    }
  }
  v2: {
    input: {
      v2Input: boolean
    }
    output: {
      v2Output: boolean
    }
  }
}

// This version does not work correctly
function io <T extends keyof Versions> (
  input: Versions[T]['input'],
  output: Versions[T]['output'],
) {}

// This should throw a type error because the input and output do not match, but it does not
io({ v1Input: true }, { v2Output: true }) 

// Adding this explicit generic correctly throws an error:
// "Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'v2Output' does not exist in type '{ v1Output: true; }'. Did you mean to write 'v1Output'?(2561)""
io<'v1'>({v1Input: true }, { v2Output: true }) 

// This version works correctly
function io2 <T extends keyof Versions> (
  input: Versions[T]['input'],
  output: Versions[T]['output'],
  key: T
) {}

// Correctly throws an error
io2({ v1Input: true }, { v2Output: true }, 'v1')

// Adding a second generic doesn't seem to help
function io3 <T extends keyof Versions, V extends Versions[T]> (
  input: V['input'],
  output: V['output'],
) {}

// Does not throw an error
io3({ v1Input: true }, { v2Output: true })
```

How can I make TypeScript correctly throw and error when I use different generic keys for different arguments?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing. Right now `Versions` is not defined so my IDE doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: have you tried setting a type constraint on Versions[T] as well: `function io <T extends keyof Versions, V extends Versions[T]> (input: V['input'],...`

Comment: @jcalz The code is now complete

Comment: @MarianTheisen It does not seem to help, I added an example

Comment: TS cannot infer generics that only appear in index positions, you'd need to refactor, possibly like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w21V4W) shows. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz This seems like a good solution! I do not understand all the syntax, but yes I would accept an answer explaining the syntax.

Comment: Okay, great. I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently TypeScript cannot infer a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter when it is only used as a key in an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  You're trying to infer `T` from `Versions[T]['input']`, but `Versions[T]` is an indexed access type using `T` as the key.  So this won't work.  Inference for `T` therefore fails and falls back to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) which is `keyof Versions`, the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the keys of `Versions`, meaning that the call to `io()` will accept any `output` and any `input` that appears in `Versions`, regardless of whether or not they are related to each other.

Maybe someday inference from generic indexes will be supported, possibly if [microsoft/TypeScript#53017](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/53017) is merged, but for now we will need to refactor your code to something where inference is known to work.

---

The easiest way to get inference working is to design things so that you are trying to infer a generic type `I` from a value of type `I` directly.  Then the inference is just "use the same type", which is straightforward (as opposed to `Versions[T]['input']` which would involve enumerating members of the constraint for `T` and trying each one out).  So we want something like:

```
function io<I extends C>(
    input: I,
    output: O<I>
) { }
```

where `C` is the constraint we want for `input`, and `O<T>` is a type which calculates the output type from `I`.

For `C` it looks like you want to accept all values of type `Versions[keyof Versions]['input']`, meaning if you have `v` of type `Versions`, and `k` of type `keyof Versions`, then `const c = v[k].input` would be of type `C`.  So that gives us

```
function io<I extends Versions[keyof Versions]['input']>(
    input: I,
    output: O<I>
) { }
```

And now we need to compute `O<I>`.  This is trickier, but one approach we can take is to write a *distributive object type* (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)).  The idea is we'd write something like `{[K in keyof Versions]: F<K>}[keyof Versions]`.  That's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) into which we immediately index with `keyof Versions` to get the full union of properties in the mapped object. For example, since `keyof Versions` is `"v1" | "v2"`, then `{[K in keyof Versions]: F<K>}[keyof Versions]` would be `{v1: F<"v1">, v2: F<"v2">}["v1" | "v2"]`, which is `F<"v1"> | F<"v2">`.  So now all we need to do is write `F<K>` so that it evaluates to the desired output type.  This will end up looking like a filtering operation; probably only one of those keys is the right one, so if `I` is (say, `Versions["v1"]["input"]`, then we want `F<"v1">` to be `Versions["v1"]["output"]`, and `F<"v2">` to be [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), so that the output is `Versions["v1"]["output"] | never` which is just `Versions["v1"]["output"]`.  Okay, so right now we have

```
function io<I extends Versions[keyof Versions]['input']>(
    input: I,
    output: { [K in keyof Versions]: F<K> }[keyof Versions]
) { }
```

And `F<K>` will have some dependency on `I`.  Here's the way I'd do it:

```
function io<I extends Versions[keyof Versions]['input']>(
    input: I,
    output: { [K in keyof Versions]:
        I extends Versions[K]['input'] ? Versions[K]['output'] : never
    }[keyof Versions]
) { }
```

Basically that's a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) were if `I` is assignable to `Versions[K]["input"]`, then we output `Versions[K]["output"]`, and otherwise `never`.  So if `I` is `Versions["v1"]["input"]`, then that conditional type will be `Versions["v1"]['output']` when `K` is `"v1"`, and `never` when `K` is `"v2"`.

---

Okay, let's try it out:

```
io({ v1Input: true }, { v2Output: true }) // error!
// -------------------> ~~~~~~~~
// 'v2Output' does not exist in type '{ v1Output: boolean; }'
// function io<{ v1Input: true; }>(
//   input: { v1Input: true; }, output: { v1Output: boolean; }): void

io({ v2Input: true }, { v2Output: true }); // okay
// function io<{ v2Input: true; }>(
//   input: { v2Input: true; }, output: { v2Output: boolean; }): void
```

Looks good.  When you call `io({v1Input:true},⋯)`, the compiler infers `I` as `{v1Input:true}`, and then calculates the type of `output` as `{v1Output:boolean}`, as expected, and complains about `{v2Output: true}`.  When you call `io({v2Input:true},⋯)`, the compiler infers `I` as `{v2Input:true}`, and then calculates the type of `output` as `{v2Output:boolean}`, as expected, and accepts `{v2Output: true}`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGrQM7APYg8gbwChlTkA3ARgC5CSyHQAHAVzFuIa7KoEkRW7ZACNs2ADYQ4IetwC+srtjaCOi7qSoB5FW1qiJUmRuQKGZngCY1J5nromG5S-1Uixk6erIXuysG6cjpqWOgH2Bp7GGr6mRApEMCwgCGA4IMg4ADy8yBAAHpAgACb46FBYuBgA2gDWEACe2DBomOkYALrVAOR2YN0dAHwAFIp9tLwANIr+gcjVANKZGfVNLeWVeB3U3qS5BUWlrRXti129AmwDyAD8x5s1C+ezVx3ItCAQ5NCKcnWNzXu7Q6RAAlIQ4kQiDhhgQKJRXPYwFAWCg5JMIc4wm5kajTOCAPQEvJQKDYKAAQiIROQAFp6QzGUzGYNkAA-DmcjnU4ndLG6frIYrYCD4EDYMB5fLADCS0DIMANJgobpw7QC-QeIwAblM3R5yCSKTSuEy2CyaoRlyEuIgurkI3GmKtOJRdtMGJeQkt2IiWuk9tBtHI2GAxShMLVLmttFtHsxoQ1Crd+N1NOwtTgDQNRtS6TNFoo0ddqPtjpjCcRNrd9s9SajvqEkR1+ODofDRCAA)